# How to parse this information from a string?

Tags: string, parsing, java.util.scanner

```
country     residents   area      capital
Andorra     71201       468       Andorra la Vella
Italien     58133509    301230    Rom
San Marino  29251       61        San Marino
```

I need to store the information (capital, residents, area, capital) in different variables. How would I go about parsing this? Notice that sometimes there are spaces in the names.

I have tried reading each token ( scanner.next() ) this fails when there are spaces in the capital or country name.

I have tried reading each line and then parsing it but I can't figure out a way to parse everything correctly since there are sometime spaces in the names. (I used indexOf() and substring() )

This is part of a bigger file but there are no spaces in the residents or area field in the entire field.

My try:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){

   String info = scanner.nextLine();
   //parse string
   int nameindex = info.indexOf(" ");
   System.out.println(info.substring(0,nameindex));
   int resindex = info.indexOf(" ", nameindex);
}
```

Comment: If the string that follows after nameindex isNumeric, then read it as next field, otherwise append the read string in the previous field with whitespace in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have a multiline string as per your question title. So why don't you simply use a regex for the whole content. Given the string is stored in the variable `data`

```
data.split("[ ]{2,}")
```

This would give the array of data as a whole. So when you have to parse it you can simply do a loop 4 elements at a time

**(edit)**

or else you can simply use this function... hope this will be easier for you.

```
List<Map<String, String>> parse(String data){
    List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    String[] lines = data.split("\n");  
    String[] keys = lines[0].split("[ ]{2,}");
    for (int i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String row[] = lines[i].split("[ ]{2,}");
        Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            rowMap.put(keys[j], row[j]);
        }
        dataList.add(rowMap);
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: Does this allow me to get the name of the country, even when it contains spaces? For example "San Marino"?

Comment: I edited the answer for yours and future readers convenient. Yes It will read even if there are spaces. But the space should be more than one in consecutive.. Try and see if this works

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how I get the Strings with the correct information from the List?

Comment: It split the string when there are more than 2 spaces present. I used REGEX to do this. If this works, then you can select it as the correct answer for this question by clicking the tick mark next to my answer.